# Automate Logic using Loops?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I need to automate the below code snippet using loops. I need to get the max values even if the availpoints reaches infinite numbers

How can i achieve it within few lines of codes

```
if (availPoints < 500 ) {
   pointsMax = 500;
   MoneyMax = 25;
}
else if (availPoints < 1000 ) {
   pointsMax = 1000;
   MoneyMax = 50;
}
else if (availPoints < 1500 ) {
   pointsMax = 1500;
   MoneyMax = 75;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Assume **availPoint** are the points a user score from 1 to 1000000(infinite too). Every 500 points is a Slot. If the points enter the next slot. The Max values **pointMax** has to be incremented by 500 & **MoneyMax** by 25.

Comment: From the provided code snippet it is unclear over what you want to loop. Could you post a bit more code that it becomes clear?

Comment: there are three code branches in your code, don't see a use case for `for` loop. Try ternary `?:` operator if willing to reduces lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not require loop.

```
    for (int availPoints = 400; availPoints < 2000; availPoints += 200) {
        int rank = availPoints / 500;
        int pointsMax = (rank + 1) * 500;
        int MoneyMax = (rank + 1) * 25;
        System.out.printf("availPoints %d -> pointMax=%d MoneyMax=%d%n",
            availPoints, pointsMax, MoneyMax);
    }
```

result:

```
availPoints 400 -> pointMax=500 MoneyMax=25
availPoints 600 -> pointMax=1000 MoneyMax=50
availPoints 800 -> pointMax=1000 MoneyMax=50
availPoints 1000 -> pointMax=1500 MoneyMax=75
availPoints 1200 -> pointMax=1500 MoneyMax=75
availPoints 1400 -> pointMax=1500 MoneyMax=75
availPoints 1600 -> pointMax=2000 MoneyMax=100
availPoints 1800 -> pointMax=2000 MoneyMax=100
```

Comment: I expected this kind of result. But I can't initialize the availPoints in the for loop. I'm getting it from the DB

Comment: The loop in my code is only used to confirm the results.  You can simply calculate `pointsMax = (availPoints / 500 + 1) * 500` and `MoneyMax = (availPoints / 500 + 1) * 25`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the max values even if the availpoints reaches infinite
>   numbers

Well this is really not good in Programming! You have to stop somewhere. Although if you have to loop until infinite (in my term, very big number), You can always use `while(true){} LOOP` with appropriate **break** statement.

If you could make it more clear that, for which kind of scenarios you want to support, then it can be more clear to us. Otherwise something like should work for you - (pseudo code - Don't try without understanding it properly )

```
long maxPoints = 0;
double MoneyMax = 0;
while(true) {
    if((availPoints == REALLY BIG MAGIC NUMBER) || (SOME OTHER CONDITION)){
        maxPoints += 500;
        MoneyMax += 25;
    }
}
```

Although as I said, you have to pick some condition based on which you will stop. If you this logic is never going to change thru out the application, you may store values in DB and play with them when needed.

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use incredibly large numbers, I suggest importing java.math.BigInteger

Here's some code that'll use a loop to find pointsMax and MoneyMax.

```
for (pointsMax = new BigInteger("500"), MoneyMax = new BigInteger("25");
pointsMax.compareTo(availPoints) != 1;) {
    pointsMax = pointsMax.add(new BigInteger("500"));
    MoneyMax = MoneyMax.add(new BigInteger("25"));
}
```

EDIT: Made it all into one loop. Also, make sure availPoints is also a BigInteger.

EDIT 2: Made it into a for loop.